# how to create a function in the repository class in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, backend, spring-repositories

I am trying to create a function in the products Repository class, this function will return all the products associated with the given parameter category. so I will pass in the
categoryName and I will get back all the products that has the same category name.

Product Repository :

```
    @Repository
    public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
    
List<Products> findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(String category);    }
```

Category Entity:

```
@Entity

public class Categories {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long categories_id;

    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product_category",fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //the name of the variable in the other class
    private Set<Products> product_category = new HashSet<>();

    public Categories(String categoryName, Set<Products> product_category) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.product_category = product_category;
    }

    public Categories() {

    }

    public Long getCategories_id() {
        return categories_id;
    }

    public void setCategories_id(Long categories_id) {
        this.categories_id = categories_id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    public Set<Products> getProduct_category() {
        return product_category;
    }

    public void setProduct_category(Set<Products> product_category) {
        this.product_category = product_category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return categoryName;

    }
}
```

Products Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long product_id;

    private String product_name;

    private double product_price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id") //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private Categories product_category;


    private String product_quantity;

    private String product_Section;

    private String product_ExpDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_item_id") //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private CartItem cartItem;


    public Long getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(Long product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }

    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }

    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }

    public double getProduct_price() {
        return product_price;
    }

    public void setProduct_price(double product_price) {
        this.product_price = product_price;
    }

    public Categories getProduct_category() {
        return product_category;
    }

    public void setProduct_category(Categories product_category) {
        this.product_category = product_category;
    }

    public String getProduct_quantity() {
        return product_quantity;
    }

    public void setProduct_quantity(String product_quantity) {
        this.product_quantity = product_quantity;
    }

    public String getProduct_Section() {
        return product_Section;
    }

    public void setProduct_Section(String product_Section) {
        this.product_Section = product_Section;
    }

    public String getProduct_ExpDate() {
        return product_ExpDate;
    }

    public void setProduct_ExpDate(String product_ExpDate) {
        this.product_ExpDate = product_ExpDate;
    }
}
```

Category Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CategoriesRepository extends JpaRepository<Categories,Long> {
}
```

Error Log:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cartItemsControllers' defined in file [E:\Spring Boot\warehouseManagementSystem\target\classes\com\example\warehouseManagementSystem\Controllers\CartItemsControllers.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'shoppingCartImp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository' defined in com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Products!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Products!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Products!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Products!
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Products!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:107) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:218) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:81) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property product found for type Products!
```

Answer (score 1):

The underscore (`_`) has a special meaning in Spring Data JPA query methods (See [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions)).

Follow Java naming conventions and rename `product_category` to `productCategory` in the `Products` class.

After that, this should work:

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
   List<Products> findByProductCategoryCategoryName(String category);
}
```

If it does not, you can also try this:

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
   List<Products> findByProductCategory_CategoryName(String category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```java
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Products, Long> {
   List<Products> findByProduct_categoryCategoryName(String category);
}
```

The property `product_category` that you used to filter is of type `Categories` and not `String` which is the parameter that you defined in the method. So that this works, you need to specify the nested `categoryName` property from `Categories` class.

Comment: it didn't work out, i updated the error and product repository

Comment: @Wim Deblauwe answer is the correct one, I forgot about the special meaning of `_` in Spring Data JPA query methods.